# Best practices for correlating clinical variables with gene expression data

Tags: correlation, bioinformatics

I am working on gene expression data from humans and disease models, where I want to correlate important measures of disease severity, i.e. clinical measurements, with the gene expression. I am trying to extract the genes which most influence the different clinical measurements. In my specific dataset we detect more than 20000 genes, of which more than 4000 are significantly differentially expressed between conditions using DESeq2.

I have had a hard time finding the best practices for this approach. I have seen people using Pearson or Spearman correlation for similar studies, but this does not seem to be a good idea given that in gene expression data:

- Many correlations will not be linear
- Many correlations will not be monotonic
- Many variables (both clinical and gene expression) will not be normally distributed
- Outliers happen relatively often

I have tried reading up on different approaches to fixing these issues and have found things like Distance Correlation, Randomized Dependence Coefficient, the whole group of Maximal Information Coefficients. However, given that I am not a statistician by trade, I have had a hard time determining what to use and which are most appropriate for gene expression data.

Therefore I wanted to ask whether there are any current best practices for correlating data which does not conform to classical correlation assumptions?

Comment: Welcome to CV! I believe you may find it useful to have a look at canonical correlation analysis.

Comment: Thank you utobi, I will! Do you think that CCA is better/will yield a more realistic result than newer methods?